# JVM chrashes with fatal error EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION wen saving file in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jvm, jvm-crash

I use wildfly8.2 and eclipse luna wth java8

when I save the java file and eclipse tryes to republish it on server the jvm chrashes and I have to restart the server every time. The error is:

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006ffd8225, pid=12012, tid=11688

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_40-b26) (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.40-b25 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 V  [jvm.dll+0x128225]

 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 C:\java\runtimes\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\bin\hs_err_pid12012.log

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

The VM arguments passed to JVM:

```
jvm_args: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:61787 -Dprogram.name=JBossTools: WildFly 8.2 -Xms64m -Xmx800m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=C:/java/runtimes/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/standalone/log/boot.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/C:/java/runtimes/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -Djboss.home.dir=C:/java/runtimes/wildfly-8.2.0.Final -Dorg.jboss.logmanager.nocolor=true -Djboss.bind.address.management=localhost -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
java_command: org.jboss.modules.Main -mp C:/java/runtimes/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -b localhost --server-config=standalone.xml -Djboss.server.base.dir=C:\java\runtimes\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\standalone
java_class_path (initial): C:\java\runtimes\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\jboss-modules.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD
```

The thread dump is here:
http://www.filedropper.com/hserrpid12012

Comment: you can see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/crashes001.html where it explains how to debug such issues -

Comment: sorry I did not finish in your case the error seems to come from jdwp.dll. do you have specific parameters passed to the JVM when you initially start it ? (like Xdebug or Xrunjdwp, you might want to try without those parameters see if you still have the error)

Comment: @FredericHenri, I've added the JVM arguments that are passed to JVM in the question, there are no Xdebug or Xrunjdwp in between, I have jboss localy and I do not use remote debugging...I understad that this parameters are for remote JVM debugging, which is not my case

Comment: you're right but there was this error in Java 1.4 [link](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4686831) which involved this parameter - even though you're on 1.8 it could have been linked somehow